# Cipher is not a Module error on A2 Hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, migration, hosting, encryption

I was trying to deploy a Ruby on Rails 3.0.3 application to A2 Hosting, I followed this tutorial ( http://wiki.a2hosting.com/index.php/Rails_3 ) using Passenger.

But I couldn't migrate my application, this is the error:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production --trace
rake aborted!
Cipher is not a module
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/openssl/cipher.rb:22
```

I looked into a lot of information about this problem and I found this: http://posterous.mclov.in/how-to-solve-the-cipher-is-not-a-module-error but I can't access to that file because the A2 Hosting doesn't allow me to have administrator accesses.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Ruby version: ruby 1.8.7
Rails version: rails 3.0.3

And this is the list of gems needed to run the application:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.3'
gem "devise", "~> 1.4.2"
gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 1.0.12'
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.3.15"
gem "rubyzip"
gem "spreadsheet", '0.6.5.7'
gem "roo", '1.9.5'
gem "schema_plus"
gem "prawn", '0.12.0'
gem "prawn-layout", '0.8.4'
gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still having trouble, we've changed the Wiki and procedures for Ruby which likely will solve your problem. The new instructions for installing Rails applications can be found here: https://my.a2hosting.com/knowledgebase.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=665

I hope that helps!
Thanks,
Andy

Comment: These instructions don't work.  The second command fails (Error installing rails: Failed to build gem native extension.)